# Invoke a service method after the Spring Boot deployed successfully

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat

I have a spring boot application and i want to invoke a service method once the application gets deployed successfully.

Ex:

```
@Service
public class MyServiceImpl implements MyUtilityService<Object, Object>{

    @Override
    public Object runOnce(Object credential) {                  
        return null;
    }
}
```

I want to invoke `myService.runOnce(...)` only after my application deployed successfully

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can register an EventListener for the ApplicationReadyEvent.

From the docs:

> Event published as late as conceivably possible to indicate that the
>   application is ready to service requests. The source of the event is
>   the SpringApplication itself, but beware of modifying its internal
>   state since all initialization steps will have been completed by then.

```
@Service
public class MyServiceImpl implements MyUtilityService<Object, Object>{

    @Override
    @EventListener(ApplicationReadyEvent.class)
    public Object runOnce(Object credential) {                  
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: You could add @Async and then sleep